# Not able to call function inside another function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making some mistake on calling the function inside another function in my jQuery object. My code is something like this:

```js
var employee = function() {
  this.init();
};

employee.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#addEmployee", this.addEmployee);
  },
  updateErrorMsg: function() {
    alert('Error');
  },
  addEmployee: function(e) {
    updateErrorMsg();
  }
}
```

I added `$(document)` to attach the event because the view is a partial view.
I am getting the error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateErrorMsg is not defined

Please assist me what mistake I am doing.

Comment: I don't see `updateModelErrorMsg` anywhere, so I guess it isn't defined ....

Comment: Or use this.updateErrorMsg();

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future. Instead of just `updateErrorMsg`, you want `this.updateErrorMsg`. But you'll also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback Separately: The *overwhelmingly-common* convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions like your `employee` are written with a capital first letter: `Employee`. You don't have to follow convention, but when asking for help it will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @Satpal: `employee.updateErrorMsg` doesn't exist. It's on `employee.prototype`, not `employee`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs i updated the error messag

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I read the above link and tried var self=this; in costructor and tried to call like self.updateErrorMsg(),but still getting the error.If possible please post the answer for above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the this reference is incorrect here, you can rewrite your code like this

```
var employee = {
    init: function() {
        var that = this;
        $(document).on("click", "#addEmployee", that.addEmployee);
    },
    updateErrorMsg: function() {
        alert('Error');
    },
    addEmployee: function(e) {
        updateErrorMsg();
    }
}
employee.init();
```